# How to disable the android keypad when using TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I am using a custom keypad to insert numbers into the textfield. I would like to disable the android keypad that pops up when the textfield is selected. I also would like to disable clickable or selectable. I only want the textfield to be focused when a number is inserted into the textfield and unfocused when empty. I do not know why the following xml code does not work and would appreciate any help.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/keyListRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.90999997"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/color_green"
       style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumber_TextInputEditText"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Here is what the pin pad and `textfield` look like:** 
[image]

Comment: Simply use a text view instead of Edittext

Answer (score 2):

To disable system keyboard automatic pop up for EditText or TextView use following:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    editTextView.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
} else {
    editTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);        
}
```

**N.B. Accepting the case when non editable text will be selectable**

To Remove EditText blinking cursor use following:

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

or,

```
mEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Default EditText and set clickable property
and on FocusChangeListener according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
 if (view != null){InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0); }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
            if (view == null) {
                view = new View(activity);
            }
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

OR this

```
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `inputType` programmatically,

```
phoneNumber_TextInputEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)
```